# Component titles containing '/' (forward slash) characters

Tags: 2011, webdav

We've had a lot of Components that have been created in the CMS using a slash in their title, which is causing WebDAV and Content Porter issues for any items named like this.

I noticed the `/` character is encoded to the value `%2F` so in theory this shouldn't be an issue, perhaps I need to do some tinkering in IIS for this to work?

Comment: Is this on Tridion R4?

Comment: Hello Chris, this is Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1.

Some more information about this:

1: Parent Publication already imported (not sure why we didn't run into this problem during that import)
2: Now we are trying to import child publication and getting errors that path doesn't exist or duplicate item exists in the publication or blue printing context.

Comment: 3: When we try to use Open with WebDev using the Context Menu, we get an error. The error goes away if we remove the "/" from Component name field.

Comment: You mention it is causing issues, but what is the exact issue, are you getting an error message you can share? Also check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826437 in case you are getting `HTTP 400 - Bad request` errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forward slash character is a special one in webserver country. Apache rejects %2F characters outright, while IIS (6 - 7.5) always translates it to an actual slash.

If you cannot convince editors to replace the forward slash with something else (which is by far the best thing you can do), then you could do two things:

For importing content through content porter you can write a tool to first translate all Tridion item titles which contain a slash to some token. Import the items in the target system and then run the tool again to rename the items back. By doing this, webdav will still not work though, but at least you get the items imported correctly.

Another option is way more tricky: use IIS rewriting to translate all %2F sequences to %252F sequences. IIS Rewrite can't do this out of the box, so you'll have to be creative. Further, you have to configure allowDoubleEscaping in IIS for it to work, but that is potentially dangerous.

So all in all - the best thing to do is to not have forward slashes in item titles.

I would further like to note that this hasn't got anything to do with Content Porter, it's just the way IIS handles forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that in webdav this issue would be there unless you manually have it encoded to some character other than `\`. Can you share what is the actual path shown in the Webdav?

Regarding Content Porter; I am not sure about your blueprinting and folder hierarchy but If you are using Content Porter 2009, then try applying following hot fixes -

1. CP_2009.0.67032
2. CP_2009.0.70433

If it is Content Porter 2009 SP1, then try applying the following hotfix:

1. CP_3.1.0.75095 - Cumulative Hotfix

These are available at following path:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/ContentPorter_2009/index.aspx ([requires login](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/about/access/index.aspx))

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj and Bart. Any of these characters (?,<>,&,/\,|,etc.) are problem when opening a page and component with WebDAV. We are using CP 2009 SP1 and will apply the hotfix and get back to you if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I just verified. It is actually SDL Content Porter Server 2009 SP2. Is there a hotfix for this version?

Comment: There are no public hotfixes released for Content Porter 2009 SP2, but I have a feeling the issue is not in CP but might be in your IIS setup?